# Passing values to an activity which I don't want to display

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've got an activity (say activity 1) which sends a bunch of extras to another activity (activity 2). I'd like those extras to be sent to activity 2, but I don't want that activity to display at all.

I'd like to send the intent to activity 2, and go straight into activity 3.

The reason for this is:

> Activity 1: User chooses some options from the UI
>
> --> Activity 2 is sent some of the chosen parameters
>
> --> A service is started which uses the parameters from activity 2
>
> Activity 3 is displayed, which is the next UI for the user.

One approach was to just start activity 2, and have activity 2 start activity 3. This doesn't work for me though, because even without a content view, activity 2 still tries to display momentarily. Also, if the back button is used from activity 3, then activity 2 shows up. I'd like to never show activity 2.  Should activity 2 be a service?

Comment: `and go straight into activity 3.` you can do the job of Activity2 in Activity A itself.

Comment: Thanks hotveryspicy. I agree that I could do the job in the activity 1, bascially activity 2 is just a helper. Is there another way to implement a helper activity/class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent an activity from being displayed after pressing BACK by using the flag : look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG%5FACTIVITY%5FNO%5FHISTORY

You can have your Activity 2 not setContentView() and nothing will be displayed

Why can't Activity 1 call Activity 3 directly ? Activity 2 needs to add data ? Perhaps you could move all that code to a subclass of your Application object and manage state through that ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer bitbox. I do need to add data to activity 2, yes. Unfortunately, a blank activity is briefly displayed for activity 2, despite having no setContentView() in that activity..

Comment: Well you'll have to design your implementation differently. Perhaps move all that stuff to an Application subclass which would be accessible from all Activities and Services...

Comment: Thanks again. I'll have to do some reading, but would you miond elaborating on the 'application subclass'? This sounds awesome! I guess I'm trying to use activity 2 as a helper class..

Comment: Your activities can call getApplication() and they will get the Application class. It turns out that you can subclass that and then cast to your instance. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm    The interesting aspect of this class is that it's a singleton